# Avoiding escape characters

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm pulling an XML feed to populate the mail's body. My XML feed usually contains escape characters (single quotes) and those are turning into "???" symbol in the delivered email.
How can I run a check on the XML feed and directly search and replace the escape characters in the final mail?

Comment: Does this ampscript code solves my purpose.

SET @CNT = Field(@XML, "Value")
_logic to find out that we are replacing the left quote_
SET @XML=Replace(@CNT,"&lsquo","'")
_logic to find out that we are replacing the right quote_
SET @XML=Replace(@CNT,"&rsquo","'")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you are using ASCII character encoding in your email. Simply open the email properties page (for the email) and change the **Target Language** to `Unicode - UTF-8`.